# what value/info will Tk() return?

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800, bg='black')
c.pack()
```

What info/value does `root` hold? I know `root = Tk()` instantiates the class Tk. And Canvas uses `root` as its parent window. I tried `print(root)` . And got the result: '.' So I just wonder What info/value does `root` hold that can be used by others?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
print(dir(root))
```

will give you a list of the `Tk` class methods.